# Center D3 geoPath US map within svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have a simple HTML file:

```
<body>
    <div class="container" id="main"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
    <script src="./wdicgeo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Corresponding JavaScript file to create a U.S. county map from D3:

```
var svg = d3.select("div#main").append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1250 800")
var path = d3.geoPath()

d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/counties-albers-10m.json").then(
    function(us) {
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation))
            .attr("fill", "#f6f6f4")
            .attr("class", "nation")
            .attr("d", path)
    }
)
```

This grabs the container, appends an `<svg>` element that automatically resizes to viewport I think, then appends a d3.geoPath U.S. nation object.

The problem is: when I append the U.S. path, it does not center within the svg, and I cannot figure out how to get it to do so.

Screenshot showing the left skew:

[image]

Is it possible to center the `<path>` within the resizing `<svg>`, which does not have a static width/height?

Comment: I believe the extent of the topojson you are using is 960 x 600, since you are not using a projection/transform/identity on the topojson but a null projection, you should set the viewport to 0,0,960,600.

Comment: That did the trick! @AndrewReid if you want to stick that in an answer, or else I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The viewport you have defined doesn't have any relationship with the data your are drawing. As you are using a null projection (the default projection of d3.geoPath), you are using the coordinates in your json as though they represent pixels. The coordinate extent of the json you are using is the space between the top left of [0,0] and the bottom right of [960,600]. As you've defined your viewport as [0,0,1250,800], there will be a margin to the right and bottom of your map as its coordinates don't cover that entire space: you should be using a viewport of [0,0,960,600].

Alternatively, you *could* reproject the data using d3.geoIdentity and fitSize to scale the json coordinates up to fit the larger viewport - however, this would be inefficient: you'd be scaling the coordinates twice: once with the identity projection and once when implementing the viewport.